# CSS: Nested DIV doesn't fill parent when using rounded corners

Tags: css

I have two divs, the parent that has rounded corners, overflow:hidden and an inline background image, and a child div that is position:absolute with a background color and opacity.

At my normal screen size, the child DIV pretty much fills the parent DIV, but I can just make out a slight line of the parent DIV on the corners.

The bigger issue is that when I zoom in to the page, at some screen sizes the child DIV is considerably smaller than the parent DIV, which obviously looks awful.

Here is my code:

```
.parent-div {
    height:350px;
    border-radius:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}
.child-div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

I've googled this but can't find a solution that works. I have tried adding the border radius on the child DIV, but this doesn't work.

[image]
FYI - when not using border radius everything seems fine.

EDIT: I think I have kind of found the issue. I have another div around all of these with padding. When I get rid of this it works. When I change the padding size I can see that is causes the issue in the image above at various padding sizes.

EDIT2: Actually, I found that what was causing the issue was the overflow:hidden on the parent div. When removing this and just ensuring I had the border radius on the child div, everything worked as expected.

Comment: try by keeping `top:0px; right:0px` as well in `.child-div`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k0jsquap/  If you add top:0 to child div, as suggested by Rama Rao M, and if your description is accurate - there should be no problems....

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you provide a working fiddle, but I think that your problem is the meassure of `.child-div`. Try this:

```
.child-div {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* here */
    border-radius: 4px; /* to apply the same that the parent */
    height: 100%; /* to make all height */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

Comment: I just created a fiddle and the issue isn't being reproduced there. I'm using bootstrap in my actual code. Wondering if that is causing an issue.

Something else weird is that, when I check with widths of the elements, they are the same yet I can clearly see the child DIV is on the left with an approx 1px space on the right with the parent DIV showing through. FYI I don't want the child div to be the same height as the parent DIV, just the same width.

Comment: If you add the three properties I purposed don't works?

Comment: It's perfectly fine on the fiddle, but on my actual one there is a strange 1px space on the right of the child DIV showing the parent DIV. When I remove border radius it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Show us an screenshot at less. Did you test this changes in your environment?