# Child div does not fill the parent div when using rounded corners

Tags: html, css

Per the title, you can see a demo of the issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dleesmusd/afngdzxw/).

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#inner{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

#inner:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

#outer{
    border: 6px solid #dcc5c5;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

I've tried various suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277403/rounded-corners-in-parent-div-not-effecting-child-divs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063762/css-nested-div-doesnt-fill-parent-when-using-rounded-corners) with no solution.

Comment: you are using margin-top:20px

Comment: looks fine to me? add border-radius to #inner as well?

Answer (score 0):

you are using **margin-top:20px;**
 in this element

```
#inner {
    height: 100px;

    background-color: #42749F;
    width: 200px;

    /* -1px here for to compansate for the outer border of the container */
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 9px 9px;
}
```

**remove margin and it will fill inside parent element**

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amoyzu30/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in that is that the child takes priority, if the parent div says:

```
text-font: Sans-Serif
```

but the child says:

```
text-font: Arial
```

the elements in the child sector take priority. In other words, the parent is the "Default". The same happens to "rounded corners" and "margin-top". The "margin-top" takes priority.

Just make sure that those two are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the border you've set on the inside division is creating problems here. Removing the border makes the child element fully fill the parent.

Is this what you were looking for? You may elaborate more if you want, in comments.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.scratcher{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.scratcher:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="scratcher">Scratcher</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's good, but when I remove the border in JSFiddle and on my desktop environment, I still get a sliver of red on the corners...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you offset the difference (`6px`) in `border-width` of the containing element (`.box_1 / #outer`), with the `border-radius` of the nested element (`#scratcher / #inner`), you will fill up the corner gaps.

Deduct `6px` from the `border-radius` value of the nested element (`#scratcher / #inner`).

```css
#inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 13px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

#inner:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#outer {
  border: 6px solid #dcc5c5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run this on my desktop, I get a 1 pixel border separating the inner div and the outer.

Comment: Bump that down to `13px` on the `border-radius` style of `#inner`. Updating answer... stand by...

Comment: There is no change with a bump down to 13px

Comment: This works on the JSFiddle, but not my desktop which uses Chrome to display... Why...

Comment: Because Computer Science, Daniel ;) Honestly, I can't say. If it works in JSFiddle I don't see why it wouldn't work in Chrome or any other browser. Stranger things have happened though. Do you get the same issue using other browsers (firefox, edge, opera, etc)? What browser are you using to access JSFiddle?

Comment: It's a weird error where depending on the zoom of my browser, it adds the 1 px spacing. I zoom once, and the spacing disappears, zoom again and it reappears. I'm content with how it is, but it would be nice to get the issue resolved absolutely.

Comment: That would be an unrelated issue (to the initial issue of the question), but you could try adding `zoom: 1.0;` to the elements in question. Want to know more? **zoom - CSS | MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40viewport/zoom